# Unable to import/export macro

Tags: macros, rust

I have a module named `macros.rs` which contains

```
/// Macro to easily implement FromError.
/// from_error!(MyError, IoError, MyError::IoError)
macro_rules! from_error {
    ( $t:ty, $err:ty, $name:path ) => {
        use std;
        impl std::error::FromError<$err> for $t {
            fn from_error(err: $err) -> $t {
                $name(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `main.rs` I import the module like this

```
#[macro_use] mod macros;
```

When I try to use `from_error` in other modules of my project, the compiler says `error: macro undefined: 'from_error!'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that the order in which you declare modules matters.

```
mod json; // json uses macros from the "macros" module. can't find them.
#[macro_use]
mod macros;

#[macro_use]
mod macros;
mod json; // json uses macros from the "macros" module. everything's ok this way.
```